# Need help to identify SMD component

Tags: diodes, identification, components, surface-mount

Labeled D53 on PCB board for diode, SOT-89 package with marking "43."

It's part of a pulse-generator section on a DC power supply, it's right by an opto-coupler.  This picture looks exactly like it, but I can't find any standard distributors in the U.S. I'm scared to throw something from Amazon.com on the board.

This [Amazon link](https://www.amazon.es/Huaban-piezas-RD43P-SOT89-Marking/dp/B01LZQ41FO) has a picture that looks exactly like the chip.

[image]

Comment: Add a photograph of the PCB and we stand a better chance. D53 is a component reference designator, so isn't going to help unless we have the component list. Do you know who the manufacturer is or anything else?

Comment: SMD codes are Mfg specific unless off patent (generic)

Comment: Could it be a BAS40 of Diodes Incorporated?

Answer (score 1):

Page 27 has your answer on bottom right.
http://www.bitsavers.org/components/centralSemiconductor/_dataBooks/1997_Central_Semiconductor_SMD_Data_Book.pdf

I searched using D53 diode codes SOT-89.  43 is just for mfg traceability or date code last digits YM or YYWW

Comment: I teach how to search/ read, you can spoon feed regardless of the rules.  -1

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 It's not about rules, its about creating a good answer. What happens to the answer when the link goes down? You might as well have not wasted your time. Thanks for fixing the answer